# Automatic OS provisioning on raspberry pi

Tags: noobs

I am doing some testings on RPi3 and I need a way to have clean OS installation after each testing.
I am currently using NOOBS to deploy my OS and by default, after reboot, RPi will go into OS instead of Recovery mode. Is there a way to decide when my RPi is going to recovery mode or reboot to OS itself?

Thanks

Comment: did you read this? .... https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/master/README.md#how-to-force-recovery-mode-being-entered-on-boot-overrides-gpio-or-keyboard-input

Comment: @goldilocks maybe i should ask in another way, how can I tell RPi go into recovery mode instead of boot into OS in the next reboot, in an automatic way?

Comment: Ah, okay.  That was jsotola's interpretation.  I think you should also change the title.  Your question is not about provisioning at all.  Your question is *"How do I force recovery mode?"*.

Comment: @goldilocks I was able to entering recovery mode by adding the argument `forcetrigger` but it's failed to install my OS automatically while in the recovery mode. I have added `silentinstall` in recovery.cmdline